Casting std::vector<T*> into std::vector<const T*>
I have this code:
class A {};

// Can't modify the signature
void DoSomething(std::vector<const T*>& outArray)
{
    // do something here and fill outArray
}

void main(void)
{
    std::vector<A*> myArray; // Can't modify the type

    DoSomething(myArray); // Doesn't compile: can't convert std::vector<A*> into std::vector<const A*>
    DoSomething(reinterpret_cast<std::vector<const A*>>(myArray)); // works but is it safe?
}

I can't modify DoSomething function signature, and I can't modify the myArray type neither.
Passing myArray directly to the function lead to compile error since the types can't be converted.
I can do a reinterpret_cast to have the proper type, but I'm not omniscient on C++ behavior and I don't know if it's really safe or if it could lead to issues later. It seams to me that's safe because it is just casting non-const to const, but I would prefer to use it as a last resort.
So my question is simple:
Beside a reinterpret_cast, is it possible to cast std::vector<A*> into std::vector<const A*>?
If not, is a reinterpret_cast really safe in this situation?
I've already read those SO questions, but these don't answers my question:
How do you cast a vector of smart pointers to a constant vector that hold smart pointers that point to constants? (similar to my use case)
Casting vector<int> to const vector<const int> (does not talk about pointers)
Does C++11 allow vector<const T>? (does not talk about pointers)
EDIT
I didn't found that answer when searching in the Internet and on SO. Thank you to the one that marked this as duplicate.
So now I understand why it is not safe to do a reinterpret_cast here.
As mentioned in the comments, a way around would be to copy the array before passing it to the function.
Unfortunately, I can't do that in my case because of performance issue.
I think the only way for my case is to duplicate the DoSomething function and change the signature.

Can't you create another vector and copy, if performance is not an issue? Edit 1: my assumption that reinterpret is okay here looks to be plain wrong :)

It's technically illegal, I believe, but it's not something that will realistically break in practice (especially if the function body is hidden in a different .cpp, and LTO isn't enabled).

Or you can add : void DoSomething(std::vector<A*>& outArray) { std::vector<const A*> constArray(outArray.begin(), outArray.end()); DoSomething(constArray); } (which might cost you some performance)

"just casting non-const to const" No. Your operation is not safe or const-correct. If this were allowed, you would be able to add a const T* to the outArray in DoSomething(), then modify the pointed to object in main. This breaks the promise of a const T*. This has been explained in one of the questions you linked to.

I think you have to copy the array. Succinctly you can call DoSomething({myArray.begin(), myArray.end()}).

Alright, I'm understanding why it is not safe now. Unfortunately, copying the array is not an option for me because of performance issues.
